# Why does Gmail and Google Docs use up so much RAM on macOS?

Tags: safari, memory, google-apps

I've always noticed that Gmail and Google Docs will take up ~1GB of RAM at any time if you have open in Safari. However, something odd happened to me just a while ago: I had a Google Docs tab open for a while, and out of nowhere it started using 8GB of RAM. Most of it had been compressed, but my memory pressure was quite high.

Is there any reason that these Google sites use up so much RAM? Should I be worried at all about this, especially if for some reason Docs starts using 8GB?

Comment: Did you find out why? I'm suffering from the same problem without any extensions enabled on Safari

Comment: Not really. I'm assuming this is just the way that Google has made their web apps, which is unfortunately. I believe this happens on all Macs and probably even PCs. I just hope macOS can manage this ram usage effectively, Nowadays I usually don't leave documents open for too long so it hasn't been an issue for me recently

If you want me to, I will happily test it out again and see if it's a real issue. What macOS version are you on?

Comment: I'm one the latest...
It's quite horrible to work with the Google suit this way as you need to force quit the pages even now and then...